# Why is my husband's iphone now getting my call history

Tags: iphone

Why is My husband's iPhone getting my call history?

Comment: could it be because he set it up that way

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It's very difficult to answer your question without knowing a bit more than what you've provided.  Please see [ask] for tips.  You can [edit] your question to include the missing info including what you've already done to resolve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you both have iPhones the only way your husband can see your call history is if both phones are using the same iCloud account.

Comment: This was documented in this article:  https://threatpost.com/iphone-call-history-synced-to-icloud-without-user-consent-knowledge/122030/